# The best way to convert time zone efficiently in MYSQL query

Tags: mysql, performance, timezone, dateadd, convert-tz

My table 'my_logs' have about 20,000,000 records, and I want to find out how many logs I have in each date within a few days.

I want to have a result like

`+------------+---------+
|    date    |  count  |
+------------+---------+
| 2016-07-01 |  1623   |
| 2016-07-02 |  1280   |
| 2016-07-03 |  2032   |
+------------+---------+`

This query below only take me milliseconds to finish, that's good

```
SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d') as date,
        COUNT(*) as count
    FROM  my_logs
    WHERE  created_at BETWEEN '2016-07-01' AND '2016-07-04'
    GROUP BY  DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

The Explain of query:

`+------------+---------+-------+-----------------------------+
|select_type |  table  | type  | possible_keys               |
+------------+---------+-------+-----------------------------+
| SIMPLE     |  my_logs| index | index_my_logs_on_created_at |
+------------+---------+-------+-----------------------------+`

`+-----------------------------+---------+----------+
|  key                        | key_len | rows     |
+-----------------------------+---------+----------+
| index_my_logs_on_created_at |  10     | 23458462 |
+-----------------------------+---------+----------+`

`+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  Extra                                                    |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+`

However, I need to convert the timezone of each record to fit the time in my country, and I need to group by the 'Date' information, so I need to convert the column itself.

Both

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)
    FROM  my_logs
    WHERE  DATE_ADD(created_at, INTERVAL 8 HOUR) BETWEEN '2016-07-01' AND '2016-07-04'
    GROUP BY  DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(created_at, INTERVAL 8 HOUR), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

and

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)
    FROM  my_logs
    WHERE  CONVERT_TZ(created_at, "+00:00", "+08:00") BETWEEN '2016-07-01' AND '2016-07-04'
    GROUP BY  DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(created_at, "+00:00", "+08:00"),
```

'%Y-%m-%d')

take me about 12s to finish the query, it is unbearable slow!!

(The Explain is the same as the query in the top)

---

I think it is common problem but I can't find a good way to deal with it, does anyone has a more efficient way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: [`convert_tz`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz) converts from one timezone to another.

Comment: Can you provide the query plans (`EXPLAIN` output) for both cases?

Comment: I add the output! Thanks. Actually, I already got the output I want, but my problem is about the efficiency. After considering the timezone issue, I can't find an efficiency way to do something which I think should be easy originally.

Comment: I meant the output of [EXPLAIN <your query>](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html), which shows what the database is actually going to do when the query runs. It helps a lot when trying to determine how to make it faster.

Comment: OK, I add it, too. The Explain is all the same.

Comment: Only miliseconds for a 20M rows table scan doesn't sound right. Can you try adding [SQL_NO_CACHE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache-in-select.html) to the first query and try it again?

Comment: The exact time comsume is 190~220 ms, after add SQL_NO_CACHE, it comes to 193 ms.

Comment: `SQL_NO_CACHE` bypasses the "Query cache", thereby providing an 'honest' timing for the query.  (Without that, you might get a bogus 1ms for a complex query on a big table.)  190~220ms is too big for the QC to be involved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Which datatype, `TIMESTAMP` vs. `DATETIME`, did you use?  (But, I'll ignore that.)

Do not "hide" an indexed column (`created_at`) inside any function (`CONVERT_TZ()`).  It makes it so that the `WHERE` clause cannot use the index and must scan the table instead.  This fix is simple:

```
WHERE created_at >= '2016-07-01' - INTERVAL 8 HOUR
  AND created_at  < '2016-07-04' - INTERVAL 8 HOUR
```

(or use `CONVERT_TZ`).  Note that I also fixed the bug wherein you included midnight from the 4th.  Note:  Even `+ INTERVAL...` is effectively a function.

Expressions in the `SELECT` and the `GROUP BY` are far less critical to performance.

Comment: Great! So the best way to do it is converting the date range in WHERE clause and converting the column in GROUP clause! That solve my problem! Thanks